# Java - Password Generator

Tags: java

I am doing this as a project. The point of it is to created a password with the types of characters you picked at the length you pick. But when i use option D, it doesn't return anything and on options B and C, no matter the length I put in, i always get a random number of characters. If you could run it, and point me in the right direction of fixing this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String password = "";
        String temp = "";
        int randLetter = 0;
        int randNumber = 0;
        int randPunct = 0;
        int charSelection = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        String lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String number = "0123456789";
        String punctuation = "!?";


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please choose what characters you would like to use.");
        System.out.println("[A] Lowercase Letters");
        System.out.println("[B] Lowercase & Uppercase Letters");
        System.out.println("[C] Lowercase, Uppercase, Numbers");
        System.out.println("[D] Lowercase, Uppercase, Numbers, Punctuation");
        System.out.print("Selection: ");
        String selection = in.next();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Select a length (1 - 14): ");
        int length = in.nextInt();

        if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                temp = lowerCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter); 
                password += temp;    
            }
        }
        else if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
            while (counter < length){
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){

                    charSelection = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10); 

                    if (charSelection < 5){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = lowerCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;  
                    }
                    else if (charSelection > 5 && charSelection < 10){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = upperCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
            while (counter < length){
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){

                    charSelection = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 17);
                    randNumber = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 9);

                    if (charSelection < 5){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = lowerCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;
                    }
                    else if (charSelection > 5 && charSelection < 10){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = upperCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;
                    }
                    else if (charSelection > 15 && charSelection < 17){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = number.substring(randNumber - 1 , randNumber);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
            while (counter < length){
                for (int i = 1; i < 0; i++){

                    charSelection = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 20); 
                    randNumber = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 9);
                    randPunct = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 2);
                    if (charSelection < 5){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = lowerCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;
                    }
                    else if (charSelection > 5 && charSelection < 10){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = upperCase.substring(randLetter - 1 , randLetter);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;
                    }
                    else if (charSelection > 15 && charSelection < 17){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = number.substring(randNumber - 1 , randNumber);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;                 
                    }
                    else if (charSelection > 17){

                        randLetter = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 26); 
                        temp = punctuation.substring(randPunct - 1 , randPunct);
                        counter++;
                        password += temp;   
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: In case "D", you have `for(int i = 1; i < 0; i++)`, you never enter that loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 0; i++){
```

This condition is never true, so the loop body never executes.

It's unclear what you really intend here, so it is hard to suggest the correct condition - do you mean `length` instead of `0`, like you do in other loops?

Answer (score 0):

Mode "B" and "C":
this loop: `while (counter < length){` will run the password generation a second time, if atleast one of the value generate in this line:

```
charSelection = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);
```

is equal to 5 (Mode "B"), or either equal to 5 or between (inclusive) 10 and 15 (Mode "C"). So basically you try `length` times to generate a new values, and repeat this process, until you've generated more characters (`counter`) than `length`, which will quite likely produce more than `length` characters. I'd recommend you eliminate the unused values and remove the `while`-loop in order to provide consistent behaviour.

Mode "D":

```
for (int i = 1; i < 0; i++){
```

This loop will terminate the generation, without ever generating a single character, since `i < 0` doesn't hold at the loop-start (`i` is initialized as 1).

And a recommendation: 
I'd recommend you split the code up into several parts, since there's plenty of reusable code:

```
Random r = new Random();

public char nextChar(String valid_chars){
    return valid_chars.charAt(r.nextInt(valid_chars.length()));
}

public String generate(String chars , int len){
    String tmp = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        tmp += nextChar(chars);

    return tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    switch(selection.toLowerCase()){
        case "a":
        {
            String password = generate("abcdefghijklmnop..." , length);
            System.out.println(password);
        }
        break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This is helps keeping the code readable, maintainable and allows simple extension to other modes.